# create a dev server like let's encrypt

Tags: security, ssl, nginx, encryption, https

I used a setup like [that](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-14-04) on my production server, which produces these files:

> cert.pem: Your domain's certificate
>
> chain.pem: The Let's Encrypt chain
>
> certificate fullchain.pem: cert.pem and chain.pem combined
>
> privkey.pem: Your certificate's private key

I would like to reproduce it as close as possible in dev, but for the `site.localhost` domain, which means I should self-sign my certificate.

In particular, I don't know how I should reproduce a `chain.pem`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this will create the two files needed, actually the other files are not needed by nginx:

```
sudo openssl req -x509 -sha256 -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -days 365 -subj "/C=US/ST=Oregon/L=Portland/O=Company Name/OU=Org/CN=localhost" -keyout /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.localhost/privkey.pem -out /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.localhost/fullchain.pem
```

Then in the nginx config file:

```
    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.localhost/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.localhost/privkey.pem;
```